# How to import .xls file to .sql with a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel

I have a excel spreadsheet:

```
id name  region  zone  
1  pokin Polon   Riny
2  lucy  yerni   kinta
...
```

And i have tables in mysql database which has `region_id` and `zone_id` instead which are foreign key to id in region and zone instead.

**users table:**

```
id name region_id zone_id
1  retre  1        1
...
```

**region table:**

```
id region_name
1   Polon
...
```

and **zone table**

```
id zone_name
1   kinta
...
```

I need to import the excel spreadsheet to users table.

Answer (score 13):

1. Export the table as you show it in the spreadsheet (with spelled out names).
2. Import that into MySQL - into table `X`, say.
3. Perform the following query to do the "normalization" as you create the desired table (with numbers instead of names):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users
        (id, name, region_id, zone_id)
    SELECT X.id, X.name, r.id, z.id
        FROM X
        LEFT JOIN region AS r ON r.region_name = X.region
        LEFT JOIN zone   AS z ON z.zone_name   = X.zone;
```

If `id` is an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then you might want to do it slightly differently.  (Leave `id` out of the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`.)

I used `LEFT` in case there are some missing regions or zoned.  In which case, you will get `NULLs` or default values for `region_id` or `zone_id`, thereby indicating that something needs fixing.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that in your .xls sheet, replace the zone and region names with the actual ids on the database for those fields. Then you can export your xls file into a csv file, and then easily import that into your database using [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html)

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
        --fields-terminated-by=, \
        --local -u root \
        -p DatabaseName \
         YourExportedFile.csv
```

A few things to consider here:

1. The path to the file when you are executing the command.
2. The fiels-terminate-by character
3. "-p DatabaseName", DatabaseName is not the password, is your database name, the password will be prompted when you execute the command.

You could import your CSV file with a SQL statement using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/user/YourExportedFile.csv"
INTO TABLE YOUR_TABLE
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Additionally if you are using any graphical MySQL client (mysql workbench, heideSql, mysqlpro, etc) you can use the import functionality instead.

Comment: i have 5000+ records in the table. replacing zone and region name with id is very tedious.

Comment: @Steve -- It takes about 4 SQL statements, no loop, no manual work: 
 `CREATE TABLE mapping ... SELECT DISTINCT zone ...` then add an id column, `UPDATE real JOIN mapping ON ... SET real.id = mapping.id WHERE real.zone = mapping.zone`.  Then `DROP COLUMN zone`.  We can discuss how to deal with subsequent `LOADs` if you like.

Comment: agree with @Rick James on this. It should be easy with new column and update if you have the mapping table and id mapping column set in stone.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming none of these tables exist, first create three CSV files users.csv, regions.csv, zone.csv.

regions.csv and zones.csv will have a single column which you can import into the DB is region_name or zone_name. I'm assuming the tables will be set up with `AUTO_INCREMENT` so the id values will take care of themselves.

To create these files in Excel get distinct values using Data > Remove Duplicates. If you have access to something like phpMyAdmin import files to the database, then import these two tables.

Creating users: 
For getting the foreign keys into the users table, I would create the users table with:

name, regions, zone, region_id, zone_id

You can import your original file into the name,regions,zone fields, then update the foreign keys.

```
UPDATE users as u SET region_id = (SELECT id FROM regions as r WHERE r.region_name = u.region)
```

Then just drop the region and zone columns.

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly we need to bring the spreadsheet in the table format in MySQL by using `Export/Import feature`

Export the table as you show it in the spreadsheet (with spelled out names).
Import that into MySQL - into table say `tempUsers`.

Perform the following query to do the **normalization** as you create the desired table (with numbers instead of names):

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users
        (id, name, region_id, zone_id)
    SELECT tempUsers.id, tempUsers.name, region.id, zone.id
        FROM X
        LEFT JOIN region AS region ON region.region_name = tempUsers.region
        LEFT JOIN zone   AS zone ON zone.zone_name   = tempUsers.zone;
```

If id is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then you might want to do it slightly differently. (Leave `id` out of the INSERT and the SELECT, because `AUTO_INCREMENT` will increase the row count by 1 whenever the new record enters).

Happy Programming

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is what i Do.

Create excel formula to generate insert script. Id would be an auto generate so just skip it.
Assuming your id is in A cell, name in B cell, region and zone in C and D respectively.

```
="INSERT INTO USER_TABLE(NAME, REGION_ID, ZONE_ID) VALUES ('"&B1&"',(select id
from region where region_name = '"&C1&"'), (select id from zone where 
zone_name = '"&D1&"')";
```

After create 1 drag the formula down to the end rows, copy the script and execute it.

Things I consider:

1. Need to patch in a lot of environment, Local, SIT, UAT, Production
   maybe. I got no DB access to Production environment so Insert script is the best way.
2. Not involve so many things and easier to change in case next time
   needed with new column added.

Answer (score 1):

For a repeated requirement, Foreign keys could be mapped in Excel.
Export region table and zone table to Excel file.
like (ex: filename: lookupmaster.xlsx)

```
region name   region Id
 Polon          1
 yerni          2
```

In the spreadsheet with actual data, add two columns as

```
region_id, zone_id
```

Get region Id for all rows using vlookup

```
VLOOKUP(B2,[lookumaster.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

To remove dependency on master, key column, 
copy region Id column and paste special as *values only* in its place.

Repeat the same for zone Id

You could remove the region and zone column from spreadsheet and import it to database.